# What is the average value of $x + \sqrt{2}\, y$ over all integer points in the ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2 < N$?

Tags: number-theory, continuity, numerical-methods, weak-derivatives

Consider the oval $x^2 + 2y^2 < N$, the number of integer points is approximately $2\pi N$.  Now consider the average:

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi N} \sum_{\{ (x,y): x^2 + 2y^2 < N\}} (x + \sqrt{2}\, y\big) $$
This is the average over all integer points inside the ellipse.  I am guessing this is close to the Riemann integeral:
$$ \int_0^1 t \, dt = \frac{1}{2} $$
I believe it is necessary to restrict to the [first quadrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), so that $x,y > 0$.

---

I plotted the function $f(N) = \#\{ (x,y) \in [0, \infty)^2 : x^2 + 2\, y^2 < N \}$ and we get a devil's staircase type function, approximating a straight line.

[image]

To approximate with a line we should say $f'(x) \approx \frac{2}{\pi} $ yet we have that $f'(x) = 0$ everywhere except at the [jump discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity).

Comment: Uh, zero, by symmetry?

Comment: Isn’t the average just zero, by symmetry? Eg $x\rightarrow -x$ and same for $y$?